# Access headers/queryparams from a WebView from Nativescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am currently working on a mobile app with Nativescript. So, I do have a WebView in the main page to log in with Spotify. After the login I have to retrieve headers/queryparams from the page in the WebView. Is this possible and if, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the `loadFinishedEvent` and check for the URL to get the queryparameters that are returning back to you. I am doing the same for third party login.

```
webViewLoaded(args) {
        const webview: WebView = <WebView>args.object;
webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (webargs: LoadEventData) => {
            let message;
            if (!webargs.error) {
                if (webargs.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('spotity') > -1) {
                    //Read the parameters and navigate

                }

                message = 'WebView finished loading of ' + webargs.url;
            } else {
                message = 'Error loading ' + webargs.url + ': ' + webargs.error;
            }
        });
}
```